# Update page every 2 sec - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, runtime-error

In this program - page should update every 2 sec.
But running is interrupted by - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined`
at this line - `document.formal.input.value="Count: " + counter;`
Why does this happen? What is wrong?

**Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Waiting example</title>
            <script>
                var counter=0;
                // call function after evty 2 sec
                id = window.setTimeout("Update();", 2000);

                function Update() {
                    counter++;
                    window.status="Count " + counter;
                    document.formal.input.value="Count: " + counter;
                    // waiting after next value
                    id=window.setTimeout("Update();", 2000);
                }               
            </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Waiting Example</h1>
            <hr>
                Value in line status & page are update evry 2 sec.
                Click the button Reset for launch counter from zero, and on stop for stop counter.
            <hr>
                <form name="formal">
                <input type="text" name="input1" size="40"><br>
                <input type="button" value="RESET" onClick="counter=0;"><br>
                <input type="button" value="STOP" onClick="window.clearTimeout(id);"><br>
            <hr>
        </body>
</html>
```

**Question:**

- How do solve this trouble?
- Why this happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your trouble. Change line to this - `document.form1.input1.value`
Here are **code:**

```
<html>
    <head><title>Timeout Example</title>
        <script>
            var counter = 0;
            // call Update function in 2 seconds after first load
            ID=window.setTimeout("Update();",2000);
            function Update() {
               counter++;
               window.status="The counter is now at " + counter;
               document.form1.input1.value="The counter is now at " + counter;
            // set another timeout for the next count
               ID=window.setTimeout("Update();",2000);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Timeout Example</h1>
            <hr><p>
                The text value below and the status line are being updated every two seconds.
                Press the RESET button to restart the count, or the STOP button to stop it.
            </p><hr>
            <form NAME="form1">
                <input TYPE="text" NAME="input1" SIZE="40"><br>
                <input TYPE="button" VALUE="RESET" onClick="counter = 0;"><br>
                <input TYPE="button" VALUE="STOP" onClick="window.clearTimeout(ID);">
            </form>
            <hr>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.formal.input1.value="Count: " + counter;
```

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/44/)**</kbd>

Comment: Why this happened? I'm beginner at Java Script. Can you display what I did wrong?

Comment: Because you need to point the `name` of your input of your form with name `formal`: `input1`

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval instead.

```
var counter=0;
// call function after evty 2 sec
id = window.setInterval(Update, 2000);

function Update() {
     counter++;
     window.status="Count " + counter;
     document.formal.elements["input1"].value="Count: " + counter;
}
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/bLet2/